# Picasso MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE/NO_STORE still increasing allocated and memory consumption

Tags: java, android, caching, memory, picasso

So, I got into an issue with memory

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

I find out it was due to `Picasso` Library which is caching images and creating error  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` so I find the solution for it and added  `android:largeHeap="true"` to my manifest and no error faced after that but does that solved my problem **NO!**
So I have few large images and few Small images so started to skip caching Large images in my app
by using `MemoryPolicy` like this:-

```
 Picasso.with(this).load('''').memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE,MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).error(R.drawable.noimagefound).placeholder( R.drawable.progress_animation ).fit().into(backdrop);
```

yet I saw incsearing memory consumption by my app:-
[image]

> which makes my app laggy after sometimes

**there is significant increase as i load large images**
Is there any proper standard to use cache or after a certain time clearing it and am i using it properly and then also increasing allocated size?
any hint will be helpful
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picasso cannot do anything if your bitmaps are really large. You need to resize the image before loading them. Add `.resize(width, height)` in the picasso chain to load smaller bitmaps.

Comment: i already have  resizing available in my url and getting a nominal size they are not that large around 40kb issue is with increasing cache it happens after event is done 30-40 times not at once

Comment: if so, there might be problem in your implementation, not allowing bitmaps to be garbage collected and creating memory leaks. BTW by default, caching is done in storage, not in the RAM, so you should not worry about it.

Comment: this question is moreover use of MemoryPolicy use in `Picasso`

Answer (score 0):

#### have you tried with Glide Library? Glide is more memory efficient comparative to Picasso.

If your app size is large and you have large number images features in your app. App start crashing Picasso library with an outOfMemory exception.

Comment: this is off topic!